# In modern browsers, what is the need for socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

I'm building a web application that is aimed at developers.  I assumed that most web developers would be using a modern browser, and thus would have support for WebSockets.  Is there any need, then, for socket.io?  Or maybe I'm just being naive about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets support is very limited. The current release version of Internet Explorer (IE 9) doesn't even support the current WebSockets specification. You need IE 10+, Firefox 11+, Chrome 16+, or a nightly build of Safari.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support

So it's a pretty big assumption that most web developers are using a browser that supports it.

Also, think about enterprise web developers. Often their corporate users are all running some older version of a browser (almost always IE) that the company has standardized on (usually to support some older Line of Business app).

In fact, [7% of all internet users and 25% of Chinese users](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) are still using *IE 6*.

There will likely be plenty of need for socket.io for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

Many proxy servers and firewalls break websockets.  Use http://socket.io-test.com to test.